# Agent based modeling: binding 2 agents together to form a H2 molecule in NetLogo (or Agents.jl)?

Tags: machine-learning, simulation, reinforcement-learning, evolutionary-algorithms, julia

Note: I got the message:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about probability, statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data visualization.

Agent based modeling is used to generate statistical data for analysis and is often the basis for reinforcement learning models as well as genetic algorithms. This use case is specifically oriented towards reinforcement learning.

Agent based modeling is a relevant topic for a data sciences oriented community.

---

I would like to simulate an agent with a specific shape. It is a H2 molecule.

It has to handle collisions on the circles, to be able to stack just like H2 molecules.

[image: H2 molecules]

I could make it in Unity3D AgentsML in 3D. But I wanted to make it in a simpler way in 2 to start experimenting.

The most simple would be to use NetLogo. I guess I can bind 2 agents together and force them to stay at a certain distance. I'm still struggling to find out how.

If it is not possible with NetLogo, I will have a look at Agents.jl that is made in Julia, and try to code that.

Thanks